# New eslint config file not catching errors in real-time

Tags: angular, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am converting my eslintrc.json to the new eslint.config.js file. When I run `npx eslint src` it works fine, however no errors are being caught in real-time. For example, if I require semicolons, lines without them will be picked up when I run eslint and I will get an error in the terminal. However, no red-line error will appear in the file. How do I enable this behavior? I am using VsCode.

Here is my eslint.config.js:

```js
// eslint.config.js
"use strict";

// Import the ESLint plugin locally
var eslintPluginExample = require("./eslint-custom-rule-example/eslint-plugin-example");
var typescriptParser = require('@typescript-eslint/parser')

module.exports = [
    {
        files: ["**/*.ts"],
        languageOptions: {
            sourceType: "module",
            ecmaVersion: 2022,
            parser: typescriptParser
        },
        // Using the eslint-plugin-example plugin defined locally
        plugins: {"example": eslintPluginExample},
        rules: {
            "example/enforce-foo-bar": "error",
            'semi': [
            'error',
            'always'
        ]
        },
    }
]
```